How to access the boot loader menu on a 2006 iMac running Lubuntu 20.04
I wiped the old MacOS and installed Lubuntu 20.04. It runs fine. But I want to try some other distros in a dual-boot setup. However, the legacy BIOS system seems to be preventing me from doing this. It will not recognize a live USB stick, but will recognize a live CD. When a CD is present, it tries to boot that first.
I want to edit the boot loader menu but
sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup

returns an error message that says it cannot access the boot loader menu. Are there any other ways to get at the boot loader? (I have tried all the Alt, Super, F12, etc keys during boot and they don't work either.)
UPDATE: I found my way to the GRUB menu and took a look at the parameters for Ubuntu (the only bootable option shown).
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ] ; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root= 'hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ] ; then
  search --no floppy --fs-uuid --set-root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2 d1c03b3b-b9fb-4ae1-94c5-b78999149452
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set-root d1c03b3b-b9fb-4ae1-94c5-b78999149452
fi
echo       'Loading Linux 5.4.0-177-generic ...'
linux      /boot/vmlinuz 5.4.0-177-generic root=UUID=d1c03b3b-b9fb-4ae1-94c5-b78999149452 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
echo       'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd     /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-177-generic

If I am understanding this correctly, it is not looking for floppy drives to boot, and seems only to look on the hard drive (hd0). Is there a way to make it look for a USB drive, and the built-in CD drive (Apple superdrive) and have it list those options for booting if there is a medium present?
Also, it seems to be saying that the BIOS and EFI are on the same partition, but I don't see how that could be the case.

The bootloader of the disk containing the Ubuntu installation can be reached as usual (SHIFT / ESC during startup), but you can't access the EFI on a mac as you would on a standard PC, the EFI on Apple devices is extremely locked down and doesn't even have an interface. If you're talking about reaching a "boot device list", then just hold option while the mac is starting up (before the dong) and you'll be presented with a list of all connected bootable devices.
